# Why does the Ruby on Rails console start very slow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

My Ruby on Rails application on Amazon EC2 (Ubuntu 10.10) runs OK, but it is very slow when starting the Ruby on Rails console on the server. It takes about 3~5 minutes to start the Ruby on Rails console. Using [top](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_%28software%29) I can see the [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) process is using 99% [CPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit) time. It's too slow. Why?

I am using Ruby 1.9.2p290, and Ruby on Rails 3.1.1. My Ruby on Rails `gemfile.lock`:

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      mail (~> 2.3.0)
    actionpack (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      rack (~> 1.3.2)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.8.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.2)
    active_utils (1.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.11)
      i18n
    activeadmin (0.4.0)
      bourbon (>= 1.0.0)
      devise (>= 1.1.2)
      fastercsv
      formtastic (>= 2.0.0)
      inherited_resources (< 1.3.0)
      jquery-rails (>= 1.0.0)
      kaminari (>= 0.13.0)
      meta_search (>= 0.9.2)
      rails (>= 3.0.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.0)
    activemerchant (1.20.2)
      active_utils (>= 1.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.11)
      braintree (>= 2.0.0)
      builder (>= 2.0.0)
      i18n
      json (>= 1.5.1)
      money (<= 3.7.1)
    activemerchant_patch_for_china (0.1.6)
      activemerchant (>= 1.4.2)
    activemodel (3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
    activerecord (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      arel (~> 2.2.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
    activesupport (3.1.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (2.2.1)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    bourbon (1.3.6)
      sass (>= 3.1)
    braintree (2.13.2)
      builder (>= 2.0.0)
    builder (3.0.0)
    devise (2.0.0)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.0.3)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      warden (~> 1.1)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.2.9)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    fastercsv (1.5.4)
    formtastic (2.0.2)
      rails (~> 3.0)
    gravatar_image_tag (1.0.0)
    guid (0.1.1)
    has_scope (0.5.1)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    inherited_resources (1.2.2)
      has_scope (~> 0.5.0)
      responders (~> 0.6.0)
    jquery-rails (1.0.19)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.6.1)
    kaminari (0.13.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    libv8 (3.3.10.4)
    mail (2.3.0)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    meta_search (1.1.3)
      actionpack (~> 3.1)
      activerecord (~> 3.1)
      activesupport (~> 3.1)
      polyamorous (~> 0.5.0)
    mime-types (1.17.2)
    money (3.7.1)
      i18n (~> 0.4)
    multi_json (1.0.3)
    orm_adapter (0.0.6)
    polyamorous (0.5.0)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.3.5)
    rack-cache (1.1)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.1.1)
      actionmailer (= 3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      activerecord (= 3.1.1)
      activeresource (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.1.1)
    railties (3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdoc (3.11)
      json (~> 1.4)
    responders (0.6.5)
    sass (3.1.14)
    sass-rails (3.1.5)
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
      sass (~> 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3.2)
    sprockets (2.0.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.4)
    therubyracer (0.9.9)
      libv8 (~> 3.3.10)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.31)
    uglifier (1.1.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
    warden (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    will_paginate (3.0.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activeadmin
  activemerchant
  activemerchant_patch_for_china
  gravatar_image_tag
  guid
  jquery-rails
  meta_search (>= 1.1.0.pre)
  rails (= 3.1.1)
  sass-rails
  sqlite3
  therubyracer
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  will_paginate
```

I also found `rake db:migrate` on server to be very slow too, just like the Ruby on Rails console.

Comment: Maybe related: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/99

Comment: I don't understand why did you downvote a valid answer. You clearly edited your question while I was posting it. Please read the updated response. Also, provide details on your instance size (which you didn't)

Comment: I am not downvote you. I am using the free EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: seems you updated your question while I was editing my answer.

It might start slow because it could be swapping. EC2 is well known for being slow and depending on the instance size you choose for EC2, a Rails application could be eating all your memory.

Previous question:

LMGTFY: http://rack.rubyforge.org/

Most likely you're using Passenger to serve your Rails application which will use a Rack adapter (and configuration) to load it.

What you're seeing there is that, your application running behind Rack.

If you think it uses a lot of memory: try reducing your dependencies, because the more gems you add, the more things will be loaded in memory.

For example, you can change therubyracer (which depends on libv8) and replace that with NodeJS altogether. That will reduce the memory footprint of your application just a little bit.

Comment: Thank you, Luis. I am currently testing a staging setup for a rather gem-heavy application using EC2 on a m1.small instance. This is a pretty small. I am experiencing the trouble in the original and updated post(s). Do you have a minimum instance size you have found to work well?